# Why does this bounty reason say that there may be more answers worthy of a bounty

Tags: discussion, bounty

I'm just curious about the language used in the following bounty reason.

> One **or more** of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional
>   bounty

It says that one **or more** of the answers is worthy of a bounty. I just started a bounty of 100 rep and it doesn't look like I can divide them among multiple answers. So why would it say that more than one is worthy if I can only award a bounty once?

Comment: @Pekka웃 But it could easily say "one of the answers is...". The way it is written now makes it sound like you can award the bounty to multiple people (at least to me)

Comment: Of course. I misread your question. I guess it's technically correct as you can award several bounties in a row to different answers... but "one of the answers" really sounds like the more logical choice, yeah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can award as many bounties per question as you like. You just have to award them one by one. The "One or more" verbiage is intended to convey this to the bounty setter so they don't feel like they have to choose exactly one answer, and to answerers so they don't get confused seeing another bounty being handed out after one has been awarded to an existing answer.

Perhaps it would be less confusing to the bounty setter if it just said "One of the answers" instead. And perhaps it's true that in the vast majority of cases only one of the answers really is getting that bounty. But I can absolutely see why they went with "One or more".